# Make [nodejs] a synonym of [node.js]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) keeps getting re-created and it keeps getting used despite being marked 'DO NOT USE'. It should be made a synonym of [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was already a [node-js](/questions/tagged/node-js) synonym, but I guess the fact that [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) was still being preserved is what prevented it from being rewritten into first the hyphenated version, then the master tag [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

I've added [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) so both the hyphenated and non-hyphenated tags are synonyms of [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) now.